# Text classification with weka

Tags: java, weka, classification, document-classification

I'm building a text classifier in java with Weka library.

First i remove stopwords, then I'm using a stemmer (e.g convert cars to car).
Right now i have 6 predefined categories. I train the classifier on
5 documents for every category. The length of the documents are similar.

The results are ok when the text to be classified is short. But when the text is longer
than 100 words the results getting stranger and stranger.

I return the probabilities for each category as following:
Probability:

[0.0015560238056109177, 0.1808919321002592, 0.6657404531908249, 0.004793498469427115, 0.13253647895234325, 0.014481613481534815]

which is a pretty reliable classification.

But when I use texts longer than around 100 word I get results like:

Probability: [1.2863123678314889E-5, 4.3728547754744305E-5, 0.9964710903856974, 5.539960514402068E-5, 0.002993481218084141, 4.234371196414616E-4]

Which is to good.

Right now Im using Naive Bayes Multinomial for classifying the documents. I have read
about it and found out that i could act strange on longer text. Might be my problem right now?

Anyone has any good idea why this is happening?

Comment: How long are the training documents? If they're quite short, there may not be enough information for the classifier when the input is longer.

Comment: Around 200-400 words. But, as I said I´m only using 5 documents per category. I think I should use more document for better classification, but i dont think it will solve the problem (of course the classification will be more accurate, but I think the error still will be there :/ )

Comment: For your >100 words test case, is it not suggesting the classified document is class 3 with P=0.996? The fact that the other numbers are so small suggests the example being classified is definitely not in those categories. Is class 3 correct?

Comment: EDIT: Actually it seems correct, i think the problem is that there is to few training documents. I will try adding some more documents and then report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple factors for this behavior. If your training and test texts are not of the same domain, this can happen. Also, I believe adding more documents for every category should do some good. 5 documents in every category is seeming very less. If you do not have more training documents or it is difficult to have more training documents, then you can synthetically add positive and negative instances in your training set (see SMOTE algorithm in detail). Keep us posted the update.